# Any reason why my Angular front end (container with a AWS Load Balancer) API calls are not hitting my Nodejs back end (container with a AWS LB)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, amazon-web-services

I have tested this setup and it works 100% end to end locally but I cannot get it to work on AWS.

**Frontend Angular**

Setup:

- Load balancer has a public DNS.
- Listener on port 80 and 443. 443 has an SSL cert.
- Availability Zones are all 3 us east (**Public**)
- Security group allows traffic from HTTP/HTTPS from my LB security group which allows 0.0.0.0/0 traffic on ports 80/443.
- ECS Cluster with a running service and 1 task (FARGATE) host Port 80.

**Backend Node**

Setup:

- Load balancer has a public DNS.
- Listener on port 80 and 443. 443 has an SSL cert.
- Availability Zones are all 3 us east (**Private**)
- Security group allows traffic from HTTP/HTTPS from my LB security group which allows 0.0.0.0/0 traffic on ports 80/443.
- ECS Cluster with a running service and 1 task (FARGATE) host Port 80.

Both are on same VPC. Note the backend load balancer has a health check that hits an API route of /api/healthcheck and it works.

Current when accessing the site I have a simple test setup where Angular will run an http request to hit the API backendloadbalancer.DNS.com/api/ig. I know this call is triggered due to a console.log.

Angular code:

```js
gettest(id): Observable<IG[]> {
  console.log('IG HAS BEEN TOUCHED');
  const url = hosturl + 'ig';
      const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': ls
      }),
      withCredentials: true,
      params: {
        'id': id,
      }
    };
 return this._http.get(url, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return <IG[]> res;
    })
  );
}
```

The backend has a route file with the following:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();

const ig = require('../controllers/ig.js');
router.get('/ig', console.log('API HIT!'),  ig.get);
```

It fails after time out. Never see any console.log of API HIT. It does not seem to be hitting it at all. Again this all works locally.

Answer (score 0):

that is a valid handler:

```
 router.get('/ig', (req, res, next) => {console.log('API HIT!'); next()},  ig.get);
```

in your example `console.log` is called upon server start, not upon request. I believe it is also not working for localhost, as the generated url `const url = hosturl + 'ig';` is wrong, or, on the other hand it could be already working on aws, and you just had no handler, and that is why it failed

Comment: Thanks for reaching out -- I switched my router call to the one you have above but I am still not seeing anything in CloudWatch where the /api/ig is hit. The const url is correct -- the variable hosturl is set to my backend load balancer dns with /api/ at the end.

Comment: If I switch out the hosturl to localhost:3000/api/ig (while running the docker containers locally) everything works as expected.

Comment: are there any errors that you get in console?

Comment: The only error I get on the nodejs side is the failure of the database request (as the database isn't public facing and must be reach via the load balancer). But in my nodejs console locally I can see API HIT and it attempting to run.